# iMessage has stopped working on MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, messages, apple-id

I have a 15-inch macbook pro that is mid-2012. The latest version of Mavericks is when the problem started, but it wasn't after the update to it. Just happened one day.

My problem started randomly one day when I tried using iMessage on my mac and all the contacts had turned red. So every time I try to send out a message from my mac, it would immediately say "not delivered."

iMessage works on my iPhone, the only problem is my macbook pro.

I have tried deleting the com.apple.ids.madrid file and that didn't work. I also tried removing my apple ID information from my phone, turning off iMessage on both of the devices, and placing my iPhone 5 in airplane mode for several minutes before turning it on and re-logging in. I can't figure out what the problem is.

I've made sure I'm logged in to my Apple ID, it's nothing like that. I've also tried creating a separate Apple ID just for the purpose of iMessage, but that did no good either.

Please help, it's been weeks and it has become very inconvenient!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use one address (for example e-mail) on all your devises, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check *iCloud* settings in *System Preferences*. Try *Account Details* to verify your connectivity to iCloud, otherwise try to Sign Out and Sign In again.

To check the *iCloud* errors while re-trying, run the following command in Terminal:

```
log stream | grep -i iCloud | grep -C5 -i error
```

To check for *Messages* errors while re-sending the message, run:

```
log stream --predicate 'processImagePath contains "Messages"'
```

See: [iMessage stopped working.. Contacts are shown as red now](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/145922/22781)